# How to dynamically generate functions in Lua?

Tags: function, lua, codegen

If I have a table `{field1=1,field2=0}` (0: ascending order, 1: descending order)

I want to get a function:

```
function(x,y)
  return x.field1 < y.field1 --there 0:'<',1:'>=' 
end
```

`field1` in the table and the sorting rule can be injected in the function.

How to generate this code dynamically?

Comment: I'd like to point out that `x.field1` is same as `x['field1']`, which is easier to alter programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Let's talk about more than just the code generation approach! As in the question, consider the need of a function:

```lua
function (x, y)
   return x.field1 --[[ < or >= ]] y.field1
end
```

For the sake of the examples assume that we have global variables:

```lua
FIRST = {field1 = 3}
SECOND = {field1 = 5}
```

#### Branching

The simplest solution (perhaps also the most typical?) that comes to my mind is a verbose `if`:

```lua
function foo (x, y, o)
   if o == nil or o == "asc" then
      return x.field1 < y.field1
   end
   if o == "dsc" then
      return x.field1 >= y.field1
   end
   error("Unknown option")
end

-- Example:
foo(FIRST, SECOND, "asc")
foo(FIRST, SECOND, "dsc")
```

Note that early returns make `else` unnecessary in this case but it might not always be true.

#### Anonymous function

But, hey, what's that? What if rather than a string option we pass something more bizarre like... something that can be called? Let's go with a simple function this time:

```lua
local asc = function (a, b) return a < b end
local dsc = function (a, b) return a >= b end

function bar (x, y, compare)
   compare = compare or asc
   return compare(x.field1, y.field1)
end

-- Example:
bar(FIRST, SECOND, asc)
bar(FIRST, SECOND, dsc)
bar(FIRST, SECOND, function (a, b) return a < b end)
```

#### Higher-order function

The previous example doesn't really look that good with a such simple operation, but let's take it as a base and let's create a function that will return us the desired function:

```lua
function make (compare)
   return function (x, y) return compare(x.field1, y.field1) end
end

-- Example:
local asc = make(function (a, b) return a < b end)
local dsc = make(function (a, b) return a >= b end)
asc(FIRST, SECOND)
dsc(FIRST, SECOND)
```

#### Actual generation

Now then, let's try something closer to code generation. Lua gives us the ability to load chunks as we go with `load*` function family.

Please note that [`load` in 5.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-load) is different from [`load` in 5.2](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) or [`load` in 5.3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load). In 5.1 you want to use [`loadstring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) instead of `load`.

```lua
function generate (op)
   return load(string.format("return function (x, y) return x.field1 %s y.field1 end", op))()
end

-- Example:
local asc = generate("<")
local dsc = generate(">=")
asc(FIRST, SECOND)
dsc(FIRST, SECOND)
```